# How to add controls to datalist in code behind, not in aspx design?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MyWeb.Data;
using MyWeb.Common;
using MyWeb.Business;
using AjaxPro;
using System.Text;

<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <div class="m_status">
                <div class="ava">
                    <a href="#">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("AvatarUS") %>' 
                        CssClass="ava_medium"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="sta_content">
                    <div class="sta_title">

                        <p class="sta_detail">
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Detail") %>'></asp:Literal>
                            </p>
                        <div class="function">
                            <a class="sta_like left" href="#">Thích</a>
                            <a class="sta_cmt left" href="#">Bình luận</a>
                            <a class="sta_share left" href="#">Chia sẻ</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>                                                  
                </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

I want to add a DataList like that in code behind(Default.aspx.cs)
How to make it?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. A `ItemTemplate` allows you to specify the structure of your `DataList` elements. You'll need to bind some data in the code behind in order to implement this DataList. I'm not entirely sure this should be done in the code behind.

Comment: I using ajaxpro to reload datalist, so I must write it in code behind, no way. Can you help me? @EricRobinson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem when I add in code behide: Default.aspx.cs

```
    namespace KetBanBonPhuong
    {
           [AjaxPro.AjaxNamespace("Default")]

           public partial class Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
           {
               protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
               {
                    AjaxPro.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(Default1));
                    if(!isPostBack)
                    {
                DataList dl = new DataList();
                dl.DataSource = GetList();
                dl.DataBind();
                this.liststatus.Controls.Add(dl);
                dl.DataSource = GetList();
                dl.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Flow;
                Literal ltr = new Literal();
                ltr.Text = "kaldfs";

                dl.Controls.Add(ltr);//Error here
             }
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the row databound event of the data list you can add some control that will hold the place for the control that you want to add, example:

In the ItemTemplate add one control to hold the control that will be addeded.

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPlaceHolder">
           <!-- the control will be added here -->
    </asp:Panel>
```

and in code behind, on RowDataBound of the data list do the following

```
Panel pnlPlaceHolder = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnlPlaceHolder");
if (pnlPlaceHolder!= null)
{
     // The new control, a button, by example          
     Button btn = new Button();
     btn.Text = "Added dinamically";
     pnlPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

This is it.

Comment: I update code in Default.aspx.cs, how add controls to datalist and bind data(Eval) like that `<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Detail") %>'></asp:Literal>`